# Cannot Install Erlang with openssl via asdf (Ubuntu 18.04.1)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openssl, erlang, asdf-vm

I am on Ubuntu 18.04.1.  Whenever I try to install any version of erlang via asdf, I get the following message:

```
APPLICATIONS DISABLED (See: /home/josh/.asdf/plugins/erlang/kerl-home/builds/asdf_18.0/otp_build_18.0.log)
 * crypto         : No usable OpenSSL found
 * jinterface     : No Java compiler found
 * ssh            : No usable OpenSSL found
 * ssl            : No usable OpenSSL found
```

I have confirmed that I have openssl installed (I have run `apt-get install libssl-dev`.  I have seen other answers suggest using a `--with-ssl` flag as a kerl configuration, so I tried running `KERL_CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS='--with-ssl=/usr/include/openssl'` but I still get the same message.  Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not sure how asdf does this, but if it leaves the compilation directory for you to inspect afterwards, look at `erts/config.log` inside it and search for `checking for OpenSSL >= 0.9.8c in standard locations`. That should tell you why it can't find OpenSSL.

Comment: the reason in the log file is `checking for OpenSSL >= 0.9.7 in standard locations... found; but not usable`.   I'm not sure why it does not see it as usable.

Comment: Right, you'd need the detailed log file to see the reason, but I guess asdf deletes it after the build...

Comment: I opened https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf/issues/391 for this.

Answer (score 2):

When install with asdf on Ubuntu you should not need to specify any custom `KERL_CONFIGURATION_OPTIONS` flags unless you've customized something. A couple commands to help you verify your OpenSSL installation are:

```
# Verify that's it on your path
$ openssl version

# See if you have more than one version installed and on your path
$ type -a openssl
```

If you see more than one OpenSSL installed you may have a problem.